# How to separate data from the same column

Tags: php

I need help separating this data from the categories column, my table looks like this

**category**

```
id  |  category  
1   |  running swimming climbing  
2   |  soccer basketball volleyball
```

I tried like this

```
$myArray = array(
    $list['category'],
);

foreach ($myArray as $keyItem => $itemValue) :
    echo '<li>' . $itemValue .PHP_EOL."</li>';
endforeach;
```

the result was this

```
running swimming climbing  
soccer basketball volleyball
```

what I want is this

```
running | swimming | climbing  
soccer | basketball | volleyball
```

remembering that the results will be within each `li`

Comment: If you mean you want to split each category string by space so you can have each as a separate list item, you can use [explode](http://php.net/explode) though normalising your scheme to not have this kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways

```
str_replace(' ', ' | ', $itemValue);
```

or

```
implode(' | ', explode(' ', $itemValue));
```

and there's many more.

So it's like:

```
echo '<li>' . str_replace(' ', ' | ', $itemValue) .PHP_EOL."</li>';
```

You are just telling the `str_replace()` to replace all spaces by `|` of the given string.

Comment: You need to pass a string. Just pass the array element inside the loop. I dont know your structure but can you try `str_replace(' ', ' | ', $itemValue['category']);`

Comment: What is the variable used for the first `explode` parameter?  `Notice:  Array to string conversion`    `echo '<li>'.implode($myArray, explode($keyItem, $itemValue)).PHP_EOL.'</li>';` `|` represent `border-right: 1px solid # ccc`